# Column specified multiple times in dynamic pivot table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have the following table with some records in it.

**Example**:

**Table**: ffortest

```
create table ffortest
(
col1 int,
col2 int
)
```

**Insertion of records**:

```
insert into ffortest values(1,2);
insert into ffortest values(3,4);
insert into ffortest values(5,6);
insert into ffortest values(7,8);
insert into ffortest values(9,2);
insert into ffortest values(1,2);
```

**Pivot Table Query**:

```
DECLARE @StuffColumn varchar(max)
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

SELECT @StuffColumn = STUFF((SELECT ','+QUOTENAME(col1)
                        FROM ffortest
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
PRINT(@StuffColumn)        

SET @SQL = ' select col2,'+ @StuffColumn +'
         from
         (
            select   col1,col2
            from ffortest
         )x
         pivot
         (
             count(col1)
             for col1 in( '+@StuffColumn +')
         )p'
PRINT(@SQL)
EXEC(@SQL)
```

**Error**: column '1' specified multiple time in p.

**Expected Result is**:

```
col2  1  9  3  5  7
-------------------
2     2  1  0  0  0
4     0  0  1  0  0
6     0  0  0  1  0
8     0  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While generating column list use `distinct` to avoid this error. Because you cannot use same column multiple times in Pivot like

```
    pivot
     (
         count(col1)
         for col1 in ([1],[3],[5],[7],[9],[1])
     )p'
```

So change your **@StuffColumn** like this.

```
SELECT @StuffColumn = STUFF((SELECT distinct ','+QUOTENAME(col1)
                        FROM ffortest
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
```